# How to iterate through numbers greater than a given number

Tags: python-3.x

So I am trying to solve a problem, where a user will input a number and you have to find the next number that has all unique digits. For example:

- Input: 1987, Output:
  2013
- Input:
  999, Output:
  1023

The way I thought of tackling this question was to go through every number after the number given by the user until I find a number that has all unique digits.

My question is that is there a way to check through every whole number greater than a number given. Until I find a specific one. So this is without a list or range. Just want to check every number until I find a specific type. Would I have to use a for loop or something similar.

Comment: [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)?

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]   

num = 5
given = 10


new = [i for i in arr if i >= num and i <= given]
```

i dont know if this is what you wanted you did not specify it.

Comment: From the OP's question, he wants to start at the given number. @Mark already provided ```range``` as the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

### The beginner way - `while True` loop

```
i = int(input()) + 1
while True:
    if digits_are_unique(i):  # Undefined
        break
    i += 1
print(i)
```

### The pro way - [`itertools.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count)

```
import itertools

i = int(input()) + 1
for i in itertools.count(i):
    if digits_are_unique(i):  # Undefined
        break
print(i)
```

### [Assignment expression - new in Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions)

Right now Python 3.8 is in beta and I don't have the interpreter to test this with, but it should work.

```
i = int(input()) + 1
while i := i + 1:
    if digits_are_unique(i):  # Undefined
        break
print(i)
```